# What's the counterpart of Oracle's Xmltable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, oracle

Need to migrate this Oracle proc to SQL Server, same table structure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure app1.MyBulkUpdate
(
   P_Arr IN CLOB
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO someone.OracleTable(DeptID, DeptName) 
    SELECT ValueID, ValueName
      FROM XMLTable('for $i in /rowset/row return $i'
                      passing xmltype.createxml(P_Arr) columns
                         DeptID VARCHAR2(200) path 'DeptID',
                         DeptName VARCHAR2(200) path 'DeptName'
                    ) x;
END;
```

Figured `P_Arr` should be prefixed with `@`, and `CLOB` could be `varchar(max)`. `rowset` and `row` are C# objects of `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`, so are like

```
<rowset ...>
  <row .../>
  ...
</rowset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming your XML looks something like this**

```
<rowset>
    <row>
        <DeptID>1005</DeptID>
        <DeptName>Some Department Name</DeptName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <DeptID>1099</DeptID>
        <DeptName>Another Department Name</DeptName>
    </row>
</rowset>
```

**The Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_MyBulkUpdate](@XML xml) 

As

Begin
    Set NoCount On;

    Insert Into [dbo].[SomeTable] (DeptID,DeptName)
    Select DeptID   = x.n.value('DeptID[1]','varchar(50)')
          ,DeptName = x.n.value('DeptName[1]','varchar(150)')
     From  @XML.nodes('rowset/row/.') x(n)

End
```

**To Execute**

```
Exec [dbo].[prc_MyBulkUpdate] @XML
```